# Spring Jar version with spring-test

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, spring-test

I am writing some JUnits for a Spring application, the Spring version used for which is

```
    <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

the dependencies are defined as

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

then in my `JUnit` test i am using the annotations as

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:config/test-application-context-datasource.xml")
```

When i am trying to execute the test case it fails to initialize, i.e. it doesn't even goes into the `@Before` method and throws below exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/type/AnnotatedTypeMetadata
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:118)
```

AnnotatedTypeMetadata is only available after spring release 4.10.0 i believe, but since i am not using that anywhere in my application and the version of my spring-test and spring-core is same, why is this even getting referred.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have incompatible versions of various Spring JARs on your classpath.

To figure out which incompatible versions (i.e., other than `3.2.8.RELEASE`) are present in your classpath, execute `mvn dependency:tree` in your project's folder.

Then ensure that you avoid having the incompatible versions on your classpath -- for example, by adding *exclusions* to your Maven POM for any dependencies that are pulling in the unwanted versions as transitive dependencies.